# Separate visa on arrival stamped/ pasted on passport for holders of Turkey e-visa?

Tags: indian-citizens, turkey, e-visas

I am an Indian Passport Holder and have obtained E-visa for Turkey. Upon arrival in Turkey, will the Immigration authorities in Istanbul, stamp/ paste another Visa on Arrival on my Passport? If yes, then how many pages in Passport are required to be free?

Comment: I haven't been to turkey since the e-visa thing started, but before it started, the thing they pasted into your passport was about the size of a quarter page, if I recall correctly.  With the stamps, it probably needs a half page.  The stated requirement might well be one page, however, but I doubt that they would bee asking for more than that.  Hopefully someone who's been there more recently than I will be able to shed some more light.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The e-Visa is fully electronic - there is nothing put in your passport at all for the visa.

Upon entering and exiting the country your passport will be stamped with a standard entry/exit stamp which will require only a small amount of space.

(Based on obtaining multiple Turkish e-visas, the most recent 3 weeks ago which has already been used to enter Turkey twice)

Comment: okay thanks  , i will apply for evisa in that case!